# Which method should I use to solve this second order differential equation?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

So I have
$$x\frac{d^2y}{dx}+\frac{dy}{dx}+xya^2=0$$
where,
$$y=y(x)$$

What I did was to just find the roots using the quadractic formula on its auxiliary equation.

I got
$$y(x)=Ae^{x(\frac{-1+\sqrt{1-4x^2a^2}}{2x})}+Be^{x(\frac{-1-\sqrt{1-4x^2a^2}}{2x})}$$

Is this correct or should I use the method of separation of variables? If so, how do I do that?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3173388/second-order-differential-equation-assistance

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is wrong. The method you are trying to use is only valid for linear equations  with constant coefficients.

Comment: Which method should I use?

Comment: The solution is a linear combination of Bessel functions of first and second kind... You will not be able to find a closed form solution that does not use special functions. Can you post the exact origin of the question?

Comment: Here's the original question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4593476/solving-the-laplace-equation-of-a-cylinder-where-v-is-a-function-of-r-phi-b