# Solving the Laplace equation of a cylinder where $V$ is a function of $r,\phi$ but not $z$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, laplacian

So I'm trying to solve this problem where there are two concentric cylinders and the voltage potential $V$ is a function of $r$ and $\phi$ but not the height $z$

I set $V$ as

$$V=f(r)g(\phi) = fg$$

so my Laplace equation would look like

$$\nabla^2V =\frac{∂^2V}{∂r^2}+\frac{1}{r}\frac{∂V}{∂r}+\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{∂^2V}{\partial\phi^2}=0$$
$$\frac{∂^2fg}{∂r^2}+\frac{1}{r}\frac{∂fg}{∂r}+\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{∂^2fg}{\partial\phi^2}=0$$
$$g\frac{∂^2f}{∂r^2}+\frac{g}{r}\frac{∂f}{∂r}+\frac{f}{r^2}\frac{∂^2g}{\partial\phi^2}=0$$
$$\frac{1}{f}\frac{∂^2f}{∂r^2}+\frac{1}{fr}\frac{∂f}{∂r}+\frac{1}{gr^2}\frac{∂^2g}{\partial\phi^2}=0$$

Then I let
$$\frac{1}{f}\frac{∂^2f}{∂r^2}+\frac{1}{fr}\frac{∂f}{∂r}=-a^2$$
$$\frac{1}{gr^2}\frac{∂^2g}{\partial\phi^2}=a^2$$

I was able to solve for $g(\phi)$ which was
$$g(\phi)=A \cosh(ar\phi)+B\sinh(ar\phi)$$
...I think,
but I'm not sure how to solve for $f(r)$

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You should totally separe $r$ and $\phi$, getting
$$
\frac{r^2 f''(r)}{f(r)}+\frac{r f'(r)}{f(r)} = -\frac{g''(\phi)}{g(\phi)}
$$

For this equality to hold for all $r,\phi$, both the rhs and lhs must be constant. The continuity of $g$ calls for a periodic solution, which explains why the constant should be positive and, furthermore, that $a \in \mathbb{Z}$.

The equation $-\dfrac{g''(\phi)}{g(\phi)} = a^2$ leads to
$$
g(\phi)  = b_1 \cos(a \phi) + b_2 \sin(a \phi).
$$

Regarding $f$, it should satisfy the equation
$$
r^2 f''(r) + rf'(r) - a^2 f(r) = 0,
$$

which leads to
$$
f(r) = c_1 \cosh(a \log r) + c_2 \sinh(a \log r).
$$

Comment: I understand how to solve for $g(\phi)$ but what exactly is the process for $f(r)$? Isn't it different from $g(\phi)$ because it has non-constant coefficients?

Comment: The solution space has dimension 2... If you can "guess" one basis element, you can get the other using the Wronskian.

Comment: @mEXsACHINE : The equation is Euler-Cauchy, with solution basis $r^a$, $r^{-a}$. Homogeneous Euler-Cauchy is equivalent to DE with constant coefficients, thus one has generally a symbolic solution. Other manually or symbolically solvable DE one can make unsolvable in this fashion by changing the coefficients a little.